# How to add a variable for each item in the index in a listview.builder

Tags: flutter, loops, for-loop, dart, listview

My goal is to generate a dynamic variable example ticket1,ticket2,ticket3 length equal to that of an index in a listview builder. I want to store a string and a double and an integer in that variable.Below is an example of the result i want and a a code sample from the project im working on.By adding a var in the top of the project the var changes for all the indexs while i want each index to have a seperate var.

```
Example
Tickets[
ticket = [ 'Phase'  , 'Price' , 'qty']
ticket1= ['EarlyBird' , '55.5' , '2' ]
]

ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: data['phases'].length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                                  d.ad
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Expanded(
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment
                                                    .spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                width:
                                                    MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width *
                                                        0.28,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  data['phases'][i]
                                                      ['phase'],
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w400,
                                                      letterSpacing: 1),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                data['phases'][i]['price']
                                                    .toString(),
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.green,
                                                    letterSpacing: 1,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w400),
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      q[i]--;
                                                    },
                                                    child: const Icon(
                                                      CupertinoIcons.minus,
                                                      color: Colors.red,
                                                      size: 16,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                                  Text('Dynamic variable based on the index'),
                                                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                                  InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      q++;
                                                    },
                                                    child: const Icon(
                                                      CupertinoIcons.plus,
                                                      color: Colors.green,
                                                      size: 16,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure `data['phases']` should look like the following:

```
data['phases'] = [
   Ticket('EarlyBird', 55.5, 2),
   Ticket('OtherTicket', 20.5, 3),
   ...
]

class Ticket {
   Ticket(this.phase, this.price, this.qty);
   final String phase;
   final double price;
   final int qty;
}
```

Then you can access it in the `ListView.builder` like the following:

```
data['phases'][i].phase
data['phases'][i].price.toString()
```